# How put scroll to top when scroller is inside Div in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, use-ref

**As you can see in the image the scroller is in the middle. Now when goes to an organization I want the scroller to go up to its start position.**

```
const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
const ListItemScroll = (props) => {
  let {
    resultList,
    indexChange,
    radioValue,
    radioHandleChange,
    setParamsInc,
    searchText,
    loading,
    noRecords
  } = props;
  const listInnerRef = useRef();

  const onScroll = () => {
    if (searchText.length === 0) {
      if (listInnerRef.current) {
        const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = listInnerRef.current;
        if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight) {
          setParamsInc((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

**This is what I am trying to do but it doesn't work**

```
  const executeScroll = () => scrollToRef(listInnerRef);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("scroll");
    executeScroll();
  }, [indexChange]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onScroll={onScroll}
        ref={listInnerRef}
        style={{ overflow: "auto", overflowX: "hidden", height: "100%" }}
      >
        List of filter values
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you create a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new with dummy data to recreate your issue?

Comment: Actually, code is very large lots of things are happening. What I want to figure out is how to scroll to the top when the filter changes (means different filter clicked). As shown in the image Scroller is in the middle and it stays in middle after getting clicked on the different filter.

Comment: after clicking on different filter the same scrollbar remains or data inside of it changes?

Answer (score 10):

Try this way:

```
const scrollToRef = (ref) => {
  ref.current.scroll({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};
```

Check example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chatterjee-2owrqu?file=/src/App.js).